# The Banach Mazur distance between n-dimensional space and $ \ell_{\infty} ^n$

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces

Let $X$ be an $n$-dimensinal space. 
Is the Banach-Mazur distance $d(X,\ell_{\infty}^n)$ less than or equal to $n$?
Is $d(X,\ell_{\infty}^n)$ less than or equal to some constant $C(n)$ depending only on $n$?

Comment: What is the Banach Mazur distance? Can you define it?

Comment: We denote by $d(X,Y)=\inf\{\|T\|\cdot\|T^{-1}\|: T \rm {is~ an ~isomorphism~ between} ~X ~\rm{and} ~Y \}$ the Banach-Mazur distance between $X$ and $Y$.

Answer (score 0):

It is [well known](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Banach%E2%80%93Mazur_compactum) in narrow circles that
$$
d(Z,\ell_2^n)\leq\sqrt{n}\tag{1}
$$
Furthermore it is easy to see straight from the definition that
$$
d(U, V)\leq d(U,W)d(W,V)\tag{2}
$$
Now set $U=X$, $V=\ell_\infty^n$, $W=\ell_2^n$ and apply $(1)$.